# Facebook, fetch more than id and name for firendlist in android

Tags: android, facebook

So bassicaly, I use this to login:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email","friends_about_me"));
    // session state call back event
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) { 
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                            Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                            Log.d(TAG, "gender = " + user.getProperty("gender"));

                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
```

I added the friends_about_me because I want to fetch the gender of the people in my friend list and in another activity, the one where I fecth my friend list:

```
private void requestFacebookFriends(final Session session) {
    Request friendrequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                Response response) {
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                friendlist = new ArrayList<Friends>();
                if (users != null) {
                    for (GraphUser user : users) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "gender = " + user.getProperty("gender"));
                        Log.d(TAG, "gender = " + user.asMap().get("gender"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    friendrequest.executeAsync();
}
```

So when I try to do the Request.newMeRequest() in the login I can fetch MY gender, but it doesn't work with my friend list, in the log, all the gender return null.
Do I miss a permission ? or what is the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request additional fields in your friend request, something like:

```
Request friendrequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(...);

Bundle params = friendrequest.getParameters();
params.putString("fields", "name,id,gender");
friendrequest.setParameters(params);
friendrequest.executeAsync();
```